# Como inserto registros cada cierta fecha con php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Resulta que tengo una app para mantenimiento preventivo.
Mi problema es el siguiente:

En la tabla "ordenes", se cargan las ordenes de cada "recurso" o equipo.
Pero los mantenimientos preventivos se realizan cada cierto tiempo, por lo tanto al cargar una orden de trabajo Preventivo, se pide cada cuanto tiempo se debe realizar, por lo que el usuario debe ver en su "desk" si tiene ordenes por vencer.

Cómo hago para que, ej: El recurso 1 tenga una orden de trabajo cada 30 días? la primera es fácil, porque al crear la primer orden de trabajo (llamemosla OT A) se suma 30 dias a la fecha de creación, pero necesito que una vez pasado el vencimiento de la OT A, se cree otra orden de trabajo B al mismo recurso automáticamente, y vencido la OT B, se cree la OT C y así...

La base ordenes tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
 id_ot, id_recurso, protocolo, tipoman, fechaot, fechavto, usercarga, 
    estado_ot, observa_orden, cierra_ot, user_cierra, fecha_cierra
```

Espero haberme explicado, muchas gracias!

Comment: Para lograrlo debes realizar una tarea programa que se ejecute cada día para que te haga la validación de las que tienen fecha vencida para que te cree el nuevo registro de manera automatica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que quieres hacer es una tarea programada, esto se logra de la siguiente manera;

lo primero que hacemos es ver si esta activo el administrador de tareas con la siguiente consulta;

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'event_scheduler';
```

por defecto esta en off, lo activamos con;

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

Hasta aca si todo esta correcto, ejecutando el primer comando deberias ver que el resultado de la primera consulta es `ON`, aca vamos a programar tu tarea

```
USE mi_base_datos; -- Base de datos sobre la que ejecutaremos la tarea

CREATE EVENT ordenes
  ON SCHEDULE 
    EVERY 1 DAY
  DO -- De aca hacia abajo vas a escribir lo que quieres que haga la tarea
```

Digamos que quieres crear una orden para aquellas que no se han cerrado en 30 días o mas, tomando en los datos que has proporcionado puedo hacer lo siguiente;

```
USE mi_base_datos;

CREATE EVENT ordenes
  ON SCHEDULE 
    EVERY 1 DAY
  DO
  INSERT INTO ordenes (campo1, campo2,campo3)  SELECT campo1,campo2,campo3 FROM ordenes WHERE DATEDIFF(fechaot,NOW()) >= 30
```

Fijate que la tarea inserta 3 campos y el `SELECT` seleciona 3 campos tambien, posteriormente a esto selecciona todos los que son mayor a 30 días por el campo `fechaot` con la función `DATEDIFF` esta retorna la diferencia en día entre 2 fechas.